# create binary column for datetime values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe

```
id     created_at            is_valid
1      2022-02-23 13:00:00     1
2      2022-02-24 12:12:00     1
3      2022-03-21 11:00:00     1
4      0000-00-00 00:00:00     0
5      null                    0
6                              0
```

How can I create a is_valid column based on the datetime column?

Answer (score 3):

Convert values to datetimes with `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), so is generate `NaN`s if not valid datetimes, so check them by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and casting to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['is_valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], errors='coerce').notna().astype(int)
```